# set associated property in initializer

Tags: swift, protocols

I have this protocol:

```
protocol TypeProtocol {

    associatedtype myType

}
```

And a class conforming to the protocol:

```
class MyClass: TypeProtocol {

    typealias myType = Any


    init() {
        //some logic here to find out what class to use

        myType = String

    }
}
```

But myType is immutable, so I can't change it to String since I already set it to Any. I don't see how to use the myType as an optional and I don't have access to the type until I initialize.

How would I get around this?

Comment: Declare the type of `myType` in the class with the data type you needed in the first place .

Comment: *some logic here to find out what class to use* is pretty ***unswifty***. Maybe generics is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example on how you do it using generics so that the type isn't defined until the class is initialised

```
protocol TypeProtocol {
    associatedtype myType
}

class MyClass<T>: TypeProtocol {

    typealias myType = T

    let data: T
    init(_ data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Example

```
let my = MyClass("abc")
print(type(of: my.data))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the way to go:

```
class MyClass<T>: TypeProtocol {

    typealias myType = T


}
```

and then

```
MyClass<Int>()
```